# Trim video tail with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have this `ffmpeg` command where it detects motion and save frames into output video.

```
ffmpeg -t 60 -i $lores -vf "select='gt(scene\,0.018)',setpts=N/(25*TB)" -acodec aac -vcodec libx265 $outfile-$tnow-x.mp4
```

Generally, over a period of 60 seconds, there would be only about 20-30 frames detected (lasting about 2 or 3 seconds at most). The output video will stay at the last frame for until it finishes 60 seconds.

Is there any way I can re-filter or trim the long tail of the video and keep only the moving frames?

My current idea is to do this.

```
ffmpeg -t 60 -i $lores -vf "select='gt(scene\,0.018)',setpts=N/(25*TB)" -an -vcodec libx265 -f nut - | ffmpeg -i - -vf "select='gt(scene\,0.018)',setpts=N/(25*TB)" $outfile-$tnow-x.mp4
```

Note: $lores is an rtsp stream.

With input from @Ricardo, I have some alternatives as follows.
'''
ffmpeg -t 300 -i $hires -an 
-vf "select='gt(scene,0.02)',setpts=N/(25*TB)" -f nut - | 
ffmpeg -i - -vf "mpdecimate" -codec libx265 $outfile-$tnow-fm.mp4
'''

I also tried this.
'''
ffmpeg -t 300 -i $hires -an 
-vf "select='gt(scene,0.02)',setpts=N/(25*TB),mpdecimate" -codec   libx265 $outfile-$tnow-fm.mp4
'''
This produces the largest file size.

Comment: the mpdecimate filter removes duplicated frames...

Comment: Thanks, @Ricardo. I am trying to search in ffmpeg doc page for mpdecimate but no keyword found. I could only found mp and decimate. But I did add mpdecimate as the third component in the first -vf. The outcome looks ok. The only con I found is the file is larger than my current double filters.

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mpdecimate maybe your video already has the right length but is displaying the wrong duration (repeating the last frame) do to some error with audio sync, try the command with -vsync 0

Comment: Thanks again. Ricaldo. Now I am exploring mpdecimate=max=5 compared to decimate=cycle=5 which I just happened to find being used. It seems mpdecimate is more suitable as it doesn't reduce the output framrate.